# Suddenly ALL RSpec tests failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

First of all my RSpec tests were working fine, then when I ran them again, every single one of them failed. This is particularly confusing as they are spread in different files. The only explanation I can think of is that some files have moved or been deleted but this is not true. I'm running Windows 8.

I would post the full error list but it is so long it doesn't fit in my command line...

You'll notice ost errors are either `ActionView::Template::Error` or `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` if that's any significance?

Also I recently added these two to my Gemfile, not sure that's what caused it though:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
```

Errors:

```
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit signin_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  52) Authentication signin with valid information
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit signin_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  53) Authentication signin with valid information
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit signin_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  54) Authentication signin with valid information
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit signin_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  55) Authentication signin with valid information
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit signin_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  56) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users when attempting to visit a protected page after signing in should rende
r the desired protected page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mlet(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }←[0m
     ←[31mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `object'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:51:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  57) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the edit page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mlet(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }←[0m
     ←[31mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `object'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:68:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  58) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the user index
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit users_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:45:in `signed_in_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:73:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  59) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mlet(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }←[0m
     ←[31mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `object'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:78:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  60) Authentication authorization as wrong user visiting Users#edit page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mlet(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }←[0m
     ←[31mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `object'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:85:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:87:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  61) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mlet(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }←[0m
     ←[31mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `new'←[0m
←[36m     # C:in `object'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:85:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:87:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  62) Static Pages should have the right links on the layout
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mvisit root_path←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  63) Static Pages Home Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit root_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  64) Static Pages Home Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit root_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  65) Static Pages Home Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit root_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  66) Static Pages Contact Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit contact_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  67) Static Pages Contact Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit contact_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  68) Static Pages Help Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit help_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  69) Static Pages Help Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit help_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  70) Static Pages About Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit about_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

  71) Static Pages About Page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit about_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error:←[0m
       ←[31mCould not find table 'users'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:22:in `current_user'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:14:in `signed_in?'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___292475144_53750136'←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__421122476_46305912'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

Finished in 0.73749 seconds
←[31m71 examples, 71 failures←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:26←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:23←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:29←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:22←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:25←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:27←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:24←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:114←[0m ←[36m# User remember token remember_token ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:88←[0m ←[36m# User when email address is already taken ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:58←[0m ←[36m# User when password confirmation is nil ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:33←[0m ←[36m# User when name is not present ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43←[0m ←[36m# User when email is not present ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:48←[0m ←[36m# User when password is not present ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:93←[0m ←[36m# User with a password that's too short ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:72←[0m ←[36m# User when email format is valid should be valid←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:62←[0m ←[36m# User when email format is invalid should be invalid←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:38←[0m ←[36m# User when name is too long ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:101←[0m ←[36m# User return value of authenticate method with valid password ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:107←[0m ←[36m# User return value of authenticate method with invalid password ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:108←[0m ←[36m# User return value of authenticate method with invalid password ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:53←[0m ←[36m# User when password doesn't match confirmation ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:98←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:99←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:104←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit with invalid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:122←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:119←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:120←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:121←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:118←[0m ←[36m# User Pages edit with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:37←[0m ←[36m# User Pages Signup Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:38←[0m ←[36m# User Pages Signup Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45←[0m ←[36m# User Pages Profile page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:46←[0m ←[36m# User Pages Profile page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:56←[0m ←[36m# User Pages signup with invalid information should not create a user←[0
m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:69←[0m ←[36m# User Pages signup with valid information should create a user←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:77←[0m ←[36m# User Pages signup with valid information after saving the user ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:78←[0m ←[36m# User Pages signup with valid information after saving the user ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:79←[0m ←[36m# User Pages signup with valid information after saving the user ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:83←[0m ←[36m# User Pages signup with valid information after saving the user followe
d by signout ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16←[0m ←[36m# User Pages index ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:17←[0m ←[36m# User Pages index ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:24←[0m ←[36m# User Pages index pagination ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:26←[0m ←[36m# User Pages index pagination should list each user←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:10←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:11←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:20←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with invalid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:21←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with invalid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:25←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with invalid information after visiting
another page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:40←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:35←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:37←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:38←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:33←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:36←[0m ←[36m# Authentication signin with valid information ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:59←[0m ←[36m# Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users when atte
mpting to visit a protected page after signing in should render the desired protected page←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:69←[0m ←[36m# Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Us
ers controller visiting the edit page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:74←[0m ←[36m# Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Us
ers controller visiting the user index ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:79←[0m ←[36m# Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Us
ers controller submitting to the update action ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:91←[0m ←[36m# Authentication authorization as wrong user visiting Users#edit
 page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:96←[0m ←[36m# Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT re
quest to the Users#update action ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:36←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages should have the right links on the layout←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:10←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages Home Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages Home Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages Home Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:32←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages Contact Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages Contact Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages Help Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages Help Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:25←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages About Page ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages About Page ←[0m

Randomized with seed 4219

  <-- Slave(1) run done!
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fchange', '0.0.5'
  gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  gem 'win32console', '1.3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end
```

Comment: “Could not find table 'users'”, well, is there actually a users table in your database?

Comment: Have you run `rake db:test:create` etc? Also, in general, post the non-ASCII-color version so it's legible.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes, I assume this can be proved by that face that this migration worked `add_column :users, :password_digest, :string` and yes I ran `bundle exec rake db:reset`, `bundle exec rake db:populate` `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` to populate the database with the faker gem

Comment: Also, the application works perfectly.

Comment: your application may work but it looks like your test database got messed up in some way. did you run db:test:prepare again?

Comment: Don’t assume. Actually check the test database.

Comment: @roninblade, yes thankyou that worked, why did I need to do it again though if I already did it once?

Comment: im assuming you had migrations pending to be included in your test database.